# Creating a dataframe using input variables pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, graph

I am trying to create a dataframe from variables that users can input. The user inputs a start and an end date, and the program searches a .csv file for the corresponding date. The .csv file has two columns, timestamp and users_holding Once it finds the date, it takes the data from the latest time (ex/ 11:55pm) and returns it to the user.

I want my user to be able to input a start date and an end date, and receive a line graph with those corresponding dates as the start and end. My plan is to create a dataframe using the start date and end date variables inputted by the user, but I don't know how to do that.

I believe that my program can find the start and end dates successfully, I'm struggling with 1) establishing a dataframe from the start and end values, and 2) using that dataframe to create a line graph. Here's a sample of my code:

```
#date range input
start_date = input("Enter a start date (YYYY-MM_DD): ")
end_date = input("Enter an end date (YYYY-MM_DD): ")

#searching for start date
start_date_match = df[df['timestamp'].str.contains(start_date)]
maxvalues_start_date_match = start_date_match.max()

#searching for end date
end_date_match = df[df['timestamp'].str.contains(end_date)]
maxvalues_end_date_match = end_date_match.max()

#establish another dataframe composed of the date range
df_range = pd.DataFrame({"timestamp":[maxvalues_start_date_match, maxvalues_end_date_match], "users_holding":[maxvalues_start_date_match, maxvalues_end_date_match]})
print(df_range)

#graph the dataframe ranging from start to end date
df_range.plot(x='timestamp', y='users_holding', kind='line')
plt.show()
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to graph the data, the Bokeh Visualization Library (https://bokeh.org/) is an excellent and very customizable way to do it. As for your DataFrame, maybe try and use the pandas date_range function to create a list of dates, and then add that to the DataFrame?

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> start_date='2020-07-01'
>>> end_date='2020-07-13'
>>> datelist=pd.date_range(start_date, end_date).tolist()
>>> df=pd.DataFrame()
>>> df['Dates']=datelist
>>> df
        Dates
0  2020-07-01
1  2020-07-02
2  2020-07-03
3  2020-07-04
4  2020-07-05
5  2020-07-06
6  2020-07-07
7  2020-07-08
8  2020-07-09
9  2020-07-10
10 2020-07-11
11 2020-07-12
12 2020-07-13
```

If the dates need to be the index of the DataFrame, `pd.set_index('dates', inplace=true)` can be utilized.

Comment: I'm getting a TypeError: Cannot convert input [timestamp

Comment: If you have a timestamp error, you could try doing ````pd.date_range(date1, date2).to_pydatetime().tolist()````